# WSO2 mediator return error message to user

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm currently trying to write a java mediator in WSO2 API manager to perform some processing before sending the message to the proxy.
The normal use cases work fine, but I'm having some trouble with exceptions.

I would like to be able to send a message back to the user from the mediator, with a message and a HTTP status code, but I can't see a way to do it.

```
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator;

public class MessageMediator extends PayloadFactoryMediator
{
    @Override
    public boolean mediate(org.apache.synapse.MessageContext synapseMessageContext)
    {
        boolean success = true;

        try{
            .... some processing
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            success = false;
            handleException(e.getMessage(), e, synapseMessageContext);
            //write message back to user
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

This is my proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AMQPProxy"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <endpoint>
        <default />
      </endpoint>
      <inSequence>
         <sequence key="MessageMediator"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

What is the correct procedure to return an error to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the error from the insequence itself without going out of wso2 esb calling another service you can do it as :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
   <format>{"Error":{"errorType":"BusinessError","details":"some details"}}</format>
   <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="400" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="messageType" expression="$trp:Accept" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<send/>
```

You can do similarly with media-type as xml see [payload factory mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator)

If you are going to return error from outsequence you can use makefault see here [Fault mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Fault+Mediator) you can try using fault mediator in insequence as well i haven't tried yet but when sending in insequence you need to use 
`<header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, if the username is empty(you can use any http code(in my sample 406)):

```
   <filter source="json-eval($.loginStatic.request.username)" regex="^null|$">
      <then>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="406" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{ "status": "ERROR!"}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/> 
      </then>       
  </filter>
```